# Logarithm of an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, math, numpy, logarithm

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import plot,show
q=10
time = range(q)
mlist=empty(q)
nlist=empty(q)
m=.9
n=(m+(1e-6))
b=3

for t in range(q):
    mlist[t]=m
    nlist[t]=n
    m=(b*(1-m)*m)
    n=(b*(1-n)*n)

zlist = mlist-nlist
zlist = abs(zlist)
plot(time, log(zlist))
show()
```

then I want to plot the graph of time,log(zlist)

and everytime I run the program, i get this error.
    "plot(time,log(zlist))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Any ideas how to either make zlist not an array so I can take the log, or just what is going wrong in my program?
Everything else works well, just that one problem.
(just for note, i have imported pylab, numpy, and math)

EDIT: The q value is relatively unimportant, but ideally will eventually be up in the 500-1000 range. and m and n have to be between 0 and 1, and b has to be between 0 and 4.

EDIT X2: It seems to be working now, i'm not sure why but it could either be a)importing log from math as well, or b, the negative value problem, but regardless, it's working well. Thank you to everyone who contributed!

Comment: You are aware that `10e-6` is a rather strange way of writing `1e-5`?

Comment: whey you say you "have imported pylab, numpy, and math" do you mean "import pylab" or "from pylab import *"? And if the latter, in what order? You need to make sure you are getting numpy.log, not math.log. Which is why you should never do "from numpy import *"!

Comment: You should include the entire relevant part of the program, including the line `plot(time, log(zlist))` and your imports

Comment: The plot command works fine for me.note that `zlist` contains quite a few negative values, so most of the logarithms simply aren't defined.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that you did `from math import *` after `from numpy import *` which means that `log` is really `math.log` which won't work on an array.

You should really not use `import *` in scripts. Instead, you should do

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

q=10
time = np.arange(q)
mlist = np.empty(q)
nlist = np.empty(q)
m=.9
n=(m+(10e-6))
b=3

for t in range(q):
  mlist[t]=m
  nlist[t]=n
  m *=b*(1-m)
  n *=b*(1-n)

zlist = mlist-nlist

plt.plot(time, np.log(zlist))
```

or, better

```
plt.semilogy(time, zlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
plot(time, map(log, zlist))
```

That will apply the log function to each number in zlist.

Comment: The NumPy version of `log` automatically applies to all items of the array -- no `map()` necessary.  It might have happened that the OP somehow ended up with `math.log` instead of `numpy.log`, but in this case the fix would be to use the right version of `log()`, not to `map()` the wrong version.